# javax.servlet.Filter response default headers

Tags: java, servlet-filters

I am modifying a legacy code, which is a java web application that every request would be dispatched by a servlet Filter.
The response argument of doFilter method already contains some headers like X-XSS-Protection and X-Content-Type-Options. By using response.reset(), headers would be cleared but i'm wondering where these headers been set?

Answer (score 0):

1. You have another filter which sets this headers.
2. Your server sets this headers in `web.xml / context.xml`